# 405 "Method POST is not allowed" in Django REST framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am new in Django REST framework. Can someone explain why I get such error, if I make a POST request to '/api/index/'

```
405 Method Not Allowed
{"detail":"Method \"POST\" not allowed."}
```

My code is following:

```
# views.py
class ApiIndexView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        return Response("ok")

# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api/index/$', views.ApiIndexView.as_view()),
]

# settings.py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissions',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    )
}
```

But if I add `<pk>` into my pattern, everything works fine:

```
# views.py
class ApiIndexView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)

    def post(self, request, pk, format=None):
        return Response("ok")

# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api/index/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.ApiIndexView.as_view()),
]
```

I am completely confused. Why it's necessary to use `<pk>` and is there a way to avoid the use of this parameter in the URL pattern?

Comment: Strange. The code you posted is working for me. Is this the full code?

Comment: Not exactly, I placed the parts that I find important. Any idea, where I can be wrong?

Comment: Well I copied the code from your question and it works. There has to be some other problem. What DRF version are you using?

Comment: Thanks, I found the problem. I just included `url(r'^api/', include(views.router.urls))` before and the `router` contains a pattern called `index`. In other words I had another view which took my response and rejected it cause of method = POST.

Comment: @Fomalhaut Thank you for including your solution! I made the same mistake.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that you have **"POST"** in `http_method_names`. Alternatively, you can write it like this:

```
def allowed_methods(self):
    """
    Return the list of allowed HTTP methods, uppercased.
    """
    self.http_method_names.append("post")
    return [method.upper() for method in self.http_method_names
            if hasattr(self, method)]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class ApiIndexView(APIView)
```

instead of this please 
 `import from rest_framework import generics`
and change it to

```
class ApiIndexView(generics.ListCreateAPIView)
```

There are many generic views. `ListCreateAPIView` is used for GET and POST and `CreateAPIView` is used only for POST methods

Comment: You saved my day. `generics.ListCreateAPIView` means `read` and `create/update`

Answer (score 2):

Is allways better not using empty spaces in url names.

So, instead of this:

```
router.register(r'', views.SomeViewSet, basename='index')
```

Do this:

```
router.register(r'some-url-name', views.SomeViewSet, basename='index')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change just:

```
# views.py
class ApiIndexView(UpdateView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        return Response("ok")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your own comment is right. You just included the **index url** before. And that main view recieve url parameter for retreiving objects, so your new view is interpreted as param.
I had the same problem in **urls.py**:

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'', views.MainViewSet, basename='index')
router.register(r'other_view', views.OtherViewSet, basename='typeservice')
```

**Solution:**

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'main', views.MainViewSet, basename='index')
router.register(r'other_view', views.OtherViewSet, basename='other_view')
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact issue too, solved it like this.

My previous code

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.CurriculumList.as_view(), name='list-curriculum'),
    path(
        '<slug:slug>/', views.SingleCurriculum.as_view(),
        name='get-curriculum'),
    path(
        'enroll/', views.EnrollCurriculum.as_view(),
        name='enroll-curriculum'),
]
```

The problem here was that when i visit url `enroll/` django maps the request to the first match, which is `<slug:slug>/`. All i had to do was change the order, so that the actual Enroll views takes precedence.

New code

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.CurriculumList.as_view(), name='list-curriculum'),
    path(
        'enroll/', views.EnrollCurriculum.as_view(),
        name='enroll-curriculum'),
    path(
        '<slug:slug>/', views.SingleCurriculum.as_view(),
        name='get-curriculum'),
]
```