# 500 error when posting django rest

Tags: javascript, django, django-rest-framework, axios

I am trying to post data using DRF modelviewsets and Axios. I have tried a couple different options so far with the same result, 500. I am able to get data using axios.get but not able to post data. I am new to rest and using ajax so I apologize if it is something obvious.

## Axios call

```
var csrftoken = Cookies.get('csrftoken');
        axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: "/api/schedules/create",
            data: {
                "emp": this.emp.emp,
                'start_time': this.startTime,
                "end_time": this.endTime,
                "date": this.today,
                "location": this.location
            },
            headers : {"X-CSRFToken" : csrftoken }
          })

    },
```

## Serializer

```
class SchedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Schedule
        fields = (
            'location',
            'emp',
            'date',
            'start_time',
            'end_time'
        )
```

## View

```
class SchedViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Schedule.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.SchedSerializer
```

## Console Output

[image]

Comment: What is the error message you're receiving from Django?

Comment: @bozdoz I added a screenshot of the console output

Comment: Right, but there should be some message.  Are there error logs you can check? Or is DEBUG mode on?

Comment: @bozdoz Debug mode is on. The page does not show any logging output, I am assuming this is because it is an ajax call

Comment: @bozdoz I realized I was missing a trailing slash in the url in the ajax call but now I get a 405 (Method Not Allowed). Any thoughts on why that might come up?

Comment: You should be posting the error from your Django console, not the browser's dev tools.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36011333/405-method-post-is-not-allowed-in-django-rest-framework